# How to use XDocument to create a IEnumerable of children elements

Tags: c#, xml

How to use XDocument to create a IEnumerable of

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<config>

  <Cars>
    <car name="SuvConfigFilename" value="this_path_is_1"/>
    <car name="SedanConfigFilename" value="this_path_is_2"/>
  </Cars>

</config>
```

I try to access all the car elements as a list, so I have :

```
XDocument centralConfig = XDocument.Load("C:\\Users\\1234\\Documents\\Visual Studio 2013\\Projects\\testStructs\\testStructs\\CentralConfig.xml");

           var query = from c in centralConfig.Descendants("Cars")
                    select new
                    {
                        Title = c.Attribute("name").Value,
                        Path = c.Attribute("value").Value                            
                    };

        Console.WriteLine("----------------------start");
        foreach (var a in query)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(a.Title.ToString());
            Console.WriteLine(a.Path.ToString());
        }
        Console.WriteLine("----------------------end");
```

very strangely, the program crashed after "---start".

I am very new to C# -- started to learn it a couple of weeks back. Can anyone take a quick look and let me know what has happened?

Thanks

Comment: use `.Descendants("car")` instead of `.Descendants("Cars")`

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<config>
 <Cars>
  <SuvConfigFilename>this_path_is_1</SuvConfigFilename>
  <SedanConfigFilename>this_path_is_2</SedanConfigFilename>
 </Cars>
</config>

XDocument centralConfig = 
XDocument.Load("C:\\Users\\1234\\Documents\\Visual Studio 
2013\\Projects\\testStructs\\testStructs\\CentralConfig.xml");

    var query = from c in centralConfig.Descendants("config").Descendants("Cars")
                select c;

    Console.WriteLine("----------------------start");
    foreach (XElement a in query)
    {         
     Console.WriteLine(a.Element("SuvConfigFilename").Value.ToString());          
     Console.WriteLine(a.Element("SedanConfigFilename").Value.ToString());
    }
     Console.WriteLine("----------------------end");
```

Comment: Please avoid posting code-only answers. If you share code, be sure to add more insight into it, for example what your code fixes or its general benefits.

Answer (score -1):

I believe your answer is that what you think is the config element is not.  Here is a simple answer that I have come up with to demonstrate how to do this.  I've tried to use your XML file so please feel free to modify my solution to fit your specific needs.

```
void Main()
{
    var text = CreateTestDoc();
    // Console.WriteLine(text); //  Proof the config file is value.

    var xDoc = XDocument.Load(new StringReader(text));
    var cars = xDoc.Root.Element("cars").Descendants();
    foreach (var car in cars)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Car Config Name: {car.Attribute("name").Value}, " +
                          $"Path: {car.Attribute("value").Value}");
    }   
}

// Define other methods and classes here
public string CreateTestDoc()
{
    return (new XDocument(new XElement("config", 
        new XElement("cars", 
            new XElement("car", 
                new XAttribute("name", "SuvConfig"),
                new XAttribute("value", "SuvPath")),
            new XElement("car",
                new XAttribute("name", "SedanConfig"),
                new XAttribute("value", "SedanPath"))
        )))).ToString();
}
```

I hope this helps, please let me know if it did.

Comment: If you are going to vote down my answer please at least include a comment as to why my answer was voted down.  Perhaps I could adjust it to more accurately answer your question.

Comment: @user152503, did my answer address your problem?  Can you please respond to let us know?